# Omit environment-content from being printed

Tags: environments, output

I've created a very simple environment for myself to make reminders/comments visible inside the document:

```
\newenvironment{todo}{~\\\color{red}}{~\\}
```

However, now I want to create a pdf for someone to proof-read and want to omit all those ToDos from the pdf. Is there a way to simply hide all the ToDos from the document by changing the environment-definition? Or maybe replace the content inside the todos with something simple like

```
<TODO>
```

Comment: Redefine your environment as being the same as `comment` in a copy of your .tex file. You may also see the `xcomment` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two options:

1. You can use the `comment` package and do `\excludecomment{todo}`, but this will insert a line break between the text before and after the environment:

[image]

2. You can use `xparse` and redefine the environment to grab its contents with `+b` and throw them away, then you have no line break:

[image]

Also, adding `\ignorespacesafterend` will avoid one spurious spaces after the `\end{todo}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\newenvironment{todo}{~\\\color{red}}{~\\\ignorespacesafterend}

% % Option 1:
% \usepackage{comment}
% \excludecomment{todo}

% Option 2:
\usepackage{xparse}
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{todo}{+b}{}{\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}

some text
\begin{todo}
  lotsa
\end{todo}
some text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I just added a '//todo' inside the empty curly brackets to just print out that word - to indicate that position in the text.